# cleartool not behaving the same between command prompt and from within a C# application

Tags: c#, clearcase, cleartool, processstartinfo

I am attempting to get the list of view privates in a particular directory from within a `C#` application.
I am using the function below to make that call with:

```
ClearCommand = "ls -r -view_only"
```

and

```
directory = @"E:\VobName\sampleDir".
```

It returns:

```
cleartool: Error: Pathname is not within a VOB: "E:\VobName\Sampledir"
```

If I do the same command in the windows command prompt from within `E:\VobName\sampleDir`, it works fine.
Any idea as to why there would be this inconsistency in the way it runs?

---

Here is the relevant code:

```
    private String RunCommand(String clearCommand, String directory)
    {
        String retVal = String.Empty;

        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
        startInfo.FileName = "cleartool";
        startInfo.Arguments = clearCommand;
        startInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        startInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
        startInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
        startInfo.WorkingDirectory = directory;

        try
        {
            // Start the process with the info we specified.
            // Call WaitForExit and then the using statement will close.
            using (Process process = Process.Start(startInfo))
            {
                //exeProcess.WaitForExit();

                // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
                using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
                {
                    retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();
                }

                if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(retVal))
                {
                    // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
                    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardError)
                    {
                        retVal = reader.ReadToEnd();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch
        {
            Debug.Assert(false, "Error sending command");
        }

        return retVal;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
E:\VobName\Sampledir
```

is a drive letter assign to a path. See the [Windows command **`subst`**](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/subst.mspx?mfr=true).
Did you try with the actual full path of the views?

```
(snapshot view)
C:\path\to\myView\VobName\Sampledir
```

or:

```
(dynamic view)
M:\myView\VobName\Sampledir
```

Comment: The paths in the original comment are the full paths. I have a partition (E:\\) that is dedicated to static views.

Comment: @JGoforth: no, it is not the full path. A snapshot view means: `<drive>:\aViewName\aVobName\someDirs`. To have a `VobName` directly following a drive letter means a `subst` has been done (through the ClearCase Explorer with a `View shortcut` for instance)